# If $U(f)=L(f)$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta, riemann-integration

The definition of Riemann integrable on my textbook is:
[image]

I want to prove if $U(f)=L(f)$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable using this definition.

The converse of this statement is easy to prove, but I wonder how I can prove it in this direction.

Definition of $U(f)$ and $L(f)$:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean $U(f)=L(f)$ for any partition $P$? If so, then let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Fix any $\delta>0$ and let $P$ be a partition with $\|P\|<\delta$. It follows that $0=U(f)-L(f)<\epsilon$ so you are done.

Comment: @JWP_HTX I have added the definition of U(f) and L(f) to my question.

Comment: Okay. In this case, do you know about the approximation properties of infima and suprema, and what the refinement of two partitions is? Those are the key pieces to answering your question.

Comment: @JWP_HTX I know what the refinement of two partitions is, not too sure about the approximation properties of infima and suprema. I have been trying for a while but don't really have an idea of how this proof will go.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then, there exists a partition $P_{1}$ such that $U(P_{1},f)-U(f)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and there exists a partition $P_{2}$ such that $L(f)-L(P_{2},f)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. These inequalities are from the approximation property for the infimum and supremum, respectively. Now, let $P$ be the common refinement so it follows that
\begin{equation} U(P_{1},f) > U(P,f)\geq U(f) \text{ and } L(P_{2},f)<L(P,f)\leq L(f)\end{equation}
and consequently,
\begin{align} 0\leq U(P,f)-L(P,f)&=U(P,f)-U(f)+L(f)-L(P,f) \\ &<U(P_{1},f)-U(f)+L(f)-L(P_{2},f)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon \end{align}
which completes the proof. I am sure, by the way, that your textbook has an explanation of the common refinement of two partitions if you have not seen this before.

Comment: I see that you let P be the common refinement of P1 and P2, but in order to prove integrable by definition, don't you need to prove that all partition with ||P||<delta satisfy the inequality?

Comment: What I wrote is enough to establish the Riemann integrability of $f$ from the condition $U(f)=L(f)$ but you are correct that it does not exactly match your textbook's definition. It is equivalent and there are many equivalent definitions of Riemann integrability.